# How to profile and "debug" Visual Studio build process?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

My visual studio build takes a very long time and I'd like to know why and how to change it.

Specifically I'm trying to build the following project: https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2

If I create buildfiles with cmake on Ubuntu 20.04 and build with make/g++, building takes 28 seconds. If I do the same on the same machine on Windows 10 and build with Visual Studio 2017, building takes over 4 minutes. I understand that msvc is not g++, but that difference is too big to be explained only by compiler differences it seems.

Comment: Are all the compiler options the same between the platforms? I know creating .pch files can take awhile.

Comment: You can create MSBuild's binary logs and inspect them with https://msbuildlog.com/